# How do I open a child document of a granted URI using ACTION_VIEW?

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, plugins, saf

Context:

Simple file explorer which shows a folder contents and allow user open any file with another app depending of the mime type

The expected behavior:

- Click in a button that launch `OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` activity
- User select a **folder A**
- Display all **folder A** contents in a list view
- When user click in a list item, launch `ACTION_VIEW` to open the file document inside another app that support rendering the contents

What I got actually:

- In the last step, the `SecurityException` is being thrown

---

The generation of my intent looks like:

```kotlin
fun someOfGrantedUris(): Uri {
  // These Uris were returned by `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` activity
  val grantedUris = contentResolver.persistedUriPermissions
  
  return grantedUris[0] // Consider this a Uri always not null and valid
}

val parentDocument = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(someOfGrantedUris())

val childDocument = parentDocument.listFiles()[0] // First child document

val uri = childDocument.uri

val intent =
  Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)

    // This is the same of just `uriWithProviderScheme = uri`
    // but in this way I can change any part of the Uri to test and debug
    val uriWithProviderScheme = Uri.Builder().let {
      it.scheme(uri.scheme)
      it.path(uri.path)
      it.query(uri.query)
      it.authority(uri.authority)
      it.build()
    }

  setDataAndType(uriWithProviderScheme, type)
}
```

But when I try to start this activity:

```kotlin
try {
  // This is not native Android but a Flutter plugin
  plugin.binding?.activity?.startActivity(intent, null)
} catch (e: SecurityException) {
  // I always fall here
}
```

- I have all runtime permissions already granted: `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
- I can also delete the child document by using `childDocument.delete()` it works fine, but when I try to launch it on `ACTION_VIEW` a SecurityException is thrown, why?

```
class java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10498 does not have permission to content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload/offline/document/primary%3ADownload/offline/Sample%20File.txt [user 0]; you could obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

Even though we can try to use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` this is not what I'm looking for since I already requested permissions before with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and by the docs:

> **Grant access** to a **directory's contents**: The `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` intent action, available on Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher, allows users to select a specific directory, ***granting your app access to all of the files and sub-directories within that directory.***

Comment: Your code looks ok.

Comment: `Even though we can try to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` Please show how you would use action_view for such an uri.

Comment: The answer is in this project: https://github.com/android/storage-samples/tree/main/ActionOpenDocumentTree and soon I'll try to add a complete answer to this post.